# Predicate for identifying von Neumann naturals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to write a formula in the language of ZF that checks for von Neumann naturals. This is how far I got:

The predicate "Ind(a)" is true, if and only if $a$ is inductive.

$$Ind(a) \leftrightarrow \varnothing \in a \; \land \forall b \, (b \in a \rightarrow b \; \cup \; \lbrace b \rbrace \in a) $$

Is the following predicate true, if and only if $a$ is a von Neumann natural?

$$Neu(a) \leftrightarrow \forall i \, (Ind(i) \rightarrow a \in i)$$

My thinking is the following:
All inductive sets contain by definition all von Neumann naturals.
Therefore the predicate $Neu(a)$ is true if $a$ is a von Neumann natural.
The axiom of infinity asserts the existence of an inductive set, which I will call $I$. The power set of $I$ contains (among others) inductive sets. One of these sets contains exactly the von Neumann naturals(for any inductive set with non-von Neumann members, there is another set in $P(I)$ which does not contain those).
If $a$ is not a von Neumann natural, then $a$ is not member of the set I just mentioned, and therefore the predicate $Neu(a)$ will be false.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You are completely correct. I have edited my question. Thank you very much. Do all inductive sets contain the von Neumann naturals?

Comment: Yes, that’s true

Comment: Your thinking is correct. Although, it is overkill. The set of Von Neumann Naturals is itself an Inductive Set. So, if a set is an element of every Inductive Set- you already have that it is a Natural. So, it's not clear how useful of a Predicate it is. You might want to try this: Neu(a) ↔ a∈i AND Ind(i) AND a is finite. Or, Neu(a) ↔ a = ∅ OR [ Succ(a) ( meaning a is the successor of one of its elements) and ∀b∈a(b = ∅ OR Succ(b) ]